# How to compress a video in React Native

Tags: javascript, video, react-native, compression, video-compression

Tried using react-native-video-processing by Shahen:

Below is the code:

```
compressVideo(source) {
    const options = {
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        bitrateMultiplier: 3,
        saveToCameraRoll: true, 
        saveWithCurrentDate: true, 
        removeAudio: true 
    };

    ProcessingManager.compress(source, options)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ base64String: data });
        })
        .catch(console.warn);
}
```

but it gives error in Android device.

> { [Error: compress error: failed. ffmpeg version 3.3.5 Copyright (c)
>   2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC) 
>   configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-nonfree --disable-network --enable-gpl --enable-ffmpeg --enable-small --disable-filters --enable-filter=copy --enable-filter=trim --enable-filter=crop --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=format --pkg-config=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-3.3-pkg-config --prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs='-lx264 -lm'  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100  libavfilter     6. 82.100 / 
>   6. 82.100  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100  libswresample   2.7.100 /  2.  7.100  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180301_141708.mp4': 
>   Metadata:    major_brand     : mp42    minor_version   : 0
>   compatible_brands: isommp42    creation_time   :
>   2018-03-01T08:47:13.000000Z    com.android.version: 7.0  Duration:
>   00:00:04.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3366 kb/s Stream #0:0(eng):
>   Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv,
>   smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x480, 3091 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.88
>   fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)    Metadata:      rotate
>   : 90      creation_time   : 2018-03-01T08:47:13.000000Z
>   handler_name    : VideoHandle    Side data:      displaymatrix:
>   rotation of -90.00 degrees    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio:aac (mp4a /
>   0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)    Metadata:
>   creation_time   : 2018-03-01T08:47:13.000000Z      handler_name    :
>   SoundHandleStream mapping:  Stream #0:0-> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264
>   (libx264))Press [q] to stop, [?] for helpError reinitializing
>   filters!Failed to inject frame into filter network: Out of memoryError
>   while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0Conversion failed!]
>   framesToPop: 1, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED' } 03-01 15:40:05.658 29497 29772
>   I ReactNativeJS: 4, { height: 640, width: 480 } 03-01 15:40:05.757
>   29497 29772 W ReactNativeJS: { [Error: compress error: failed. ffmpeg
>   version 3.3.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  built
>   with gcc 4.8 (GCC)  configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-nonfree --disable-network --enable-gpl --enable-ffmpeg --enable-small --disable-filters --enable-filter=copy --enable-filter=trim --enable-filter=crop --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=format --pkg-config=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-3.3-pkg-config --prefix=/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/Users/kesha/Projects/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs='-lx264 -lm'  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100  libavfilter     6. 82.100 / 
>   6. 82.100  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100  libswresample   2.7.100 /  2.  7.100  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
>   'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180301_141708.mp4': 
>   Metadata:    major_brand     : mp42    minor_version   : 0
>   compatible_brands: isommp42    creation_time   :
>   2018-03-01T08:47:13.000000Z    com.android.version: 7.0  Duration:
>   00:00:04.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3366 kb/s Stream #0:0(eng):
>   Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv,
>   smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x480, 3091 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.88
>   fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)    Metadata:      rotate
>   : 90      creation_time   : 2018-03-01T08:47:13.000000Z
>   handler_name    : VideoHandle    Side data:      displaymatrix:
>   rotation of -90.00 degrees    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio:aac (mp4a /
>   0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)    Metadata:
>   creation_time   : 2018-03-01T08:47:13.000000Z      handler_name    :
>   SoundHandleStream mapping:  Stream #0:0-> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264
>   (libx264))Press [q] to stop, [?] for helpError reinitializing
>   filters!Failed to inject frame into filter network: Out of memoryError
>   while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0Conversion failed!]
>   framesToPop: 1, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED' }

**Any solution for this issue or any other method to compress the video before uploading.**

Comment: Did you find any solution for video compression?

Answer (score 2):

Have a try on the following code to successfully compress videos in react-native. My compressing result => 7.5mb into 1.48mb. This command require **full-gpl** package

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import {RNFFmpeg} from "react-native-ffmpeg"
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

function processVideo(videoUrl, callback) {
  const finalVideo = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/audioVideoFinal.mp4`;

  cacheResourcePath(videoUrl).then((rVideoUrl) => {
   const str_cmd = `-y -i ${rVideoUrl} -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast  ${finalVideo}`;
   
    RNFFmpeg.execute(
      str_cmd,
    ).then((result) => {
      if (result === 0) {
        RNFS.unlink(rVideoUrl);

        callback({
          videoPath:
            Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + finalVideo : finalVideo,
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

async function cacheResourcePath(sourcePath) {
  const uriComponents = sourcePath.split('/');
  const fileNameAndExtension = uriComponents[uriComponents.length - 1].replaceAll(' ','');

  const destPath = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/${fileNameAndExtension}`;

  await RNFS.copyFile(sourcePath, destPath);
  return destPath;
}
```

Comment: does this work with expo ? and also on iOS also or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [rn-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob) for android to convert the path first as the URI you get is temporary in the case of android and can't be found in the directory,

```
const res = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(SOURCE_URI);
src = "file://" + res.path;

ProcessingManager.compress(src, options)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ base64String: data });
    })
    .catch(console.warn);
```

This will resolve the path issue.